"Index error: list index out of range" on my blackjack project
I am trying to create blackjack in python, but I am getting a list error. I do not know why. I am calling a function (drawing cards) that modifies the lists (Yes, the variables are global), but the terminal is saying that my lists are empty. Keep in mind, I am just learning python, so there may be some inefficiencies in my code (i.e. not using enumerate, repeating code
Here is my code:
import random
def cash_out():
    global playerchips
    total_value = playerchips[0] * 10 + playerchips[1] * 5 + playerchips[2] * 1
    print(f"\nYou are cashing out. You have a total of ${total_value}.")
    exit()
print("Welcome to the solo-blackjack casino.py. You will start with $45 dollars in chips.")

player1cards = []
dealercards = []
card = ''

dealt_cards = []

def draw_cards():
    global player1cards, dealercards  # Use global keyword to modify global variables

    for _ in range(2):  # Deal two cards to each
        card = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
        while card in dealt_cards:  # Check if the card has already been dealt
            card = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
        player1cards.append(card)
        dealt_cards.append(card)  # Add the dealt card to the list of dealt cards
        
        card = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
        while card in dealt_cards:  # Check if the card has already been dealt
            card = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
        dealercards.append(card)  # Add the dealt card to the list of dealt cards
        dealt_cards.append(card)
import sys
aces = 0
import time
dealt_cards=[]
def calculate_hand_value(cards):
    value = 0
    aces = 0
    for card in cards:
        card_value = cardlist[card]
        if card_value == 11:
            aces += 1
        value += card_value
    while value > 21 and aces:
        value -= 10
        aces -= 1
    return value

def is_soft_17(cards):
    # This function checks if the dealer has a "soft 17"
    value = calculate_hand_value(cards)
    if value == 17:
        for card in cards:
            if cardlist[card] == 11:
                return True
    return False

cardlist = {
    '2 of Spades': 2,
    '2 of Hearts': 2,
    '2 of Clubs': 2,
    '2 of Diamonds': 2,
    '3 of Spades': 3,
    '3 of Hearts': 3,
    '3 of Clubs': 3,
    '3 of Diamonds': 3,
    '4 of Spades': 4,
    '4 of Hearts': 4,
    '4 of Clubs': 4,
    '4 of Diamonds': 4,
    '5 of Spades': 5,
    '5 of Hearts': 5,
    '5 of Clubs': 5,
    '5 of Diamonds': 5,
    '6 of Spades': 6,
    '6 of Hearts': 6,
    '6 of Clubs': 6,
    '6 of Diamonds': 6,
    '7 of Spades': 7,
    '7 of Hearts': 7,
    '7 of Clubs': 7,
    '7 of Diamonds': 7,
    '8 of Spades': 8,
    '8 of Hearts': 8,
    '8 of Clubs': 8,
    '8 of Diamonds': 8,
    '9 of Spades': 9,
    '9 of Hearts': 9,
    '9 of Clubs': 9,
    '9 of Diamonds': 9,
    '10 of Spades': 10,
    '10 of Hearts': 10,
    '10 of Clubs': 10,
    '10 of Diamonds': 10,
    'Jack of Spades': 10,
    'Jack of Hearts': 10,
    'Jack of Clubs': 10,
    'Jack of Diamonds': 10,
    'Queen of Spades': 10,
    'Queen of Hearts': 10,
    'Queen of Clubs': 10,
    'Queen of Diamonds': 10,
    'King of Spades': 10,
    'King of Hearts': 10,
    'King of Clubs': 10,
    'King of Diamonds': 10,
    'Ace of Spades': 11,
    'Ace of Hearts': 11,
    'Ace of Clubs': 11,
    'Ace of Diamonds': 11
}



# Player starts with $45 in chips: 5 red ($5 each), 10 white ($1 each), 1 green ($10 each)
playerchips = [1, 5, 10]
print("Red chips are worth $5, White chips $1, and green chips $10")

def rungame():
    player1cards = []
    dealercards = []
    draw_cards()
    global playerchips
    print(f"You have {playerchips[2]} white chips, {playerchips[1]} red chips, and {playerchips[0]} green chips.")
    while True:
        Chipsbet = input("Type how many chips you would like to put in in the format of green, red, white. Example: 1, 2, 4 would be 1 green, 2 red, and 4 white: ")
        Chipsbet = Chipsbet.split(", ")
        if len(Chipsbet) != 3:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter the number of chips for each color.")
            continue
        try:
            bet_green, bet_red, bet_white = map(int, Chipsbet)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter numeric values.")
            continue
        if bet_green < 0 or bet_red < 0 or bet_white < 0:
            print("Invalid input. Chips cannot be negative.")
            continue
        total_bet = bet_green * 10 + bet_red * 5 + bet_white * 1
        if total_bet == 0:
            print("You need to bet at least one chip.")
            continue
        if bet_green > playerchips[0] or bet_red > playerchips[1] or bet_white > playerchips[2]:
            print("You don't have enough chips to make that bet.")
            continue
        break
    # Deduct the bet from the player's chips
    playerchips[0] -= bet_green
    playerchips[1] -= bet_red
    playerchips[2] -= bet_white

    # Calculate total bet in dollars
    total_bet = bet_green * 10 + bet_red * 5 + bet_white * 1

    player1cards = []
    dealercards = []
    draw_cards()
    print(f'''
You have been dealt the cards '{player1cards[0]}' and '{player1cards[1]}'. The dealer has been dealt '{dealercards[0]}' and an unknown card.''')
    
    while True:
        hitorout = input("Would you like to 'hit' or 'stand'? ").lower()
        if hitorout == 'hit':
            dealcard = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
            del cardlist[card]
            player1cards.append(dealcard)
            print(f"You have been dealt '{dealcard}'.")
            player_value = calculate_hand_value(player1cards)
            print(f"Your current hand value is {player_value}.")
            if player_value > 21:
                print("Bust! You exceeded 21.")
                break
        elif hitorout == 'stand':
            print("You chose to stand.")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please type 'hit' or 'stand'.")

    player_value = calculate_hand_value(player1cards)
    dealer_value = calculate_hand_value(dealercards)

    while dealer_value < 17 or (dealer_value == 17 and is_soft_17(dealercards)):
        dealcard = random.choice(list(cardlist.keys()))
        del cardlist[card]

        dealercards.append(dealcard)
        dealer_value = calculate_hand_value(dealercards)
        print(f"The dealer currently has the cards:")
        for p in range(len(dealercards)):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(dealercards[p])
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The dealer has either hit a soft 17 or has a card value under 17. They must draw another card.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"The dealer has drawn '{dealcard}'. Current dealer value: {dealer_value}")

    print("The dealer's final hand is: ")
    for y in range(len(dealercards)):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(dealercards[y])
    time.sleep(1.5)
    if player_value > 21:
        print("You busted. You lose your bet.")
    elif dealer_value > 21:
        print("The dealer busted. You win!")
        playerchips[0] += bet_green * 2
        playerchips[1] += bet_red * 2
        playerchips[2] += bet_white * 2
    elif player_value > dealer_value:
        print("You won! You get double the chips you put in.")
        playerchips[0] += bet_green * 2
        playerchips[1] += bet_red * 2
        playerchips[2] += bet_white * 2
    elif player_value < dealer_value:
        print("You lost. You lose the chips you put in.")
    else:
        print("It's a tie. Dealer wins, you lose the chips you put in.")

    print(f"Your current chip count is: {playerchips[0]} green chips, {playerchips[1]} red chips, and {playerchips[2]} white chips.")
rungame()
while True:
    runanother=input("Do you want to 'play again', or 'cash out'? ").lower()
    if runanother=='cash out':
        cash_out()
    elif runanother == 'play again':
        rungame()
    else:
        print("Invalid response.")

I tried a lot. I asked chatGPT for help, and it didn't. I made sure that the variables were global, moved the draw_cards() function to before the lists were used, and more.
bump

That's a lot of code... what's the error and the line it occurs on?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Without checking your code in detail, I noticed that you initialize player1cards = [] and
dealercards = [] three times, once at the beginning of your code (around line 8), again after def rungame() and then within rungame a second time just before printing which cards you have been dealt. Maybe that's the issue?
